# Database design: How can I design my database in order to not have repeated entries of the same product?

Tags: database-design

I have a table products and table sizes. Each product can have multiple sizes. How can I design my database in order to not have repeated entries of the same product?

Comment: Is this homework?  If so please mark it [Homework].  Please show us what you have done so far.  This is not `www.do_my_homework_for_me.com`

Comment: It's not homework. It's me trying to understand normalization. I've already created the database and tables but I couldn't figure the mapping table...

Comment: This is an m:n relation. You can't avoid repetition of either Your products or Your sizes. That's why You're supposed to use memory efficient primary keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical approach to a many-many relationship is to have a mapping table called Product_Size that contains the Primary Keys of each table.

```
create table Product (
    id uniqueidentifier not null,
    name varchar(255),
    primary key (id))

create table Size (
    id int,
    name varchar(255),
    primary key (id))

create table Product_Size (
    productId uniqueidentifier,
    sizeId int,
    primary key (productId, sizeId),
    foreign key (productId) references Product(id),
    foreign key (sizeId) references Size(id))
```

Comment: Except I would not use a unique identifer as the PK in a table for perfornance reasons unless I had no other choice. An INT is a better choice most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
product Table

 1. product id 
 2. product name
 ......

Product Size

 1. Id
 2. ProductId( Foreign key form product table)
 3. Size
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends, each product can have multiple sizes, but can different products have the same size?

If they can't then you have a one-many relationship and you need a ProductSize table which holds the primary key of the product.

`ProductSize (SizeID, ProductID, Size)`

If they can then you have a many to many relationship and you can break this up by having three tables, Product, Size and ProductSize, where Product contains products, Size contains sizes and ProductSize maps each product to the sizes available, by holding the primary key of Product and Size.

```
Product (ProductID, ProductName)
Size (SizeID, SizeName)
ProductSize (ProductID, SizeID)
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
Products
----------
ProductID    PK, auto increment int
ProductName
....

Sizes
------- 
SizeID      PK, auto increment int
SizeInfo
....

ProductSizes
--------------
ProductID   PK, FK to Products.ProductID
SizeID      PK, FK to Sizes.SizeID
```